# How to get “Modified By” value for “custom list in datasheet view” app?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-api

We get the "Modified By" attribute for all the files we upload to a document library in SharePoint Online. However, I am not able to fetch the field for "custom list in datasheet view" and "Calendar" applications.  I am using GetListItems() API of SiteData webservice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopmentprevious/thread/e52978d3-f40f-4b6d-a24b-bdb7dcb4c1a9/) post can help to resolve your problem?

Andrew